# Angular2 Form too slow when it's not the only component in the page

Tags: forms, angular, performance, text, input

There's a problem that I have since days, and I've searched a lot on the internet, without finding any question. I had this form that is showed with other components (such as the navbar). It was too slow and I was getting crazy. I copy and pasted the form from the official [angular.io guide](https://angular.io/guide/forms) and nothing has improved.
Then I tried to display it without the other components of my website and it's magically performing fine. The point is that I have to put it as a part of a component, or at least a component, but I obviously need it to be reached through the *router-outlet*. 
This is the structure of my *app.component.html*:

***app.component.html***

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<app-item-form></app-item-form>
```

The navbar is a normal navbar, while the *item-form.component.html* has the following structure:

***item-form.component.html***

```
<div class="container">
    <div [hidden]="submitted">
        <h1>Form</h1>
        <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #itemForm="ngForm">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="it_name">Nome</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="it_name" required [(ngModel)]="it_name" name="it_name" #name="ngModel">
            </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!itemForm.form.valid">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The *item-form.component.ts* contains just the variables that are binded in the html, and a boolean, just like the example of the official *angular.io* guide.

The performance analysis from Google Chrome gave me [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cm5aH.png), and I don't think that those calls to functions like map, DoJoin, etc are normal. As the image shows, they are the ones that slow down my form and I can't find the reason why they are called.

Yes, I'm using **angular2-jwt**, but why does it interfere with the form?
 This component has no dependencies on that library. And why if I edit my *app.component.html* in this way (i.e.: leaving only the form):

```
<app-item-form></app-item-form>
```

everything works without any delay?
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

### Update 1

After some analysis, I noticed that the actual problem is not the presence of another component, but the use of my authentication service, which uses angular2-jwt token, inside my navbar. This is the relevant code of **navbar.component.html**:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li *ngIf="authService.loggedIn()" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions] = "{exact:true}"><a [routerLink]="['/dashboard']">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li *ngIf="authService.loggedIn()" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions] = "{exact:true}"><a [routerLink]="['/profile']">Profile</a></li>

            <li *ngIf="!authService.loggedIn()" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions] = "{exact:true}"><a [routerLink]="['/login']">Login</a></li>
            <li *ngIf="!authService.loggedIn()" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions] = "{exact:true}"><a [routerLink]="['/register']">Register</a></li>
            <li *ngIf="authService.loggedIn()"><a (click)="onLogoutClick()" href="#">Logout</a></li>
          </ul>
```

where authService.loggedIn() is a function inside **auth.service.ts**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt';

    @Injectable()
    export class AuthService {
      authToken: any;
      user: any;

      constructor(private http: Http) { }

      loggedIn() {
            return tokenNotExpired('id_token');
          }
    }
```

## Solved

The problem was the fact that in the *ngIf I put a function, against the Angular2 best practices. So the loggedIn() function was called every time something happened in the application.

Comment: would it be feasible to reproduce it in a plunker? i think this is the angular starter plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5?p=catalogue

Comment: What happens when the template is just<app-navbar></app-navbar> without any codes from <app-item-form>? If there is a delay in this component/template, then the problem is in this template. Have a nice day.

Comment: @harold_mean2 the app runs normally, the problem is in <app-item-form> when it’s not the only component. If it’s di the only one it is fast because the scripting (spotted with the performance tools) are not executed. I’m missing the link between that scripts and the presence of other components.

Comment: @AlexanderTaylor I’ll try, and when I can, I’ll post it here, thank you.